# Using strtotime with TimeZone

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have a problem. I want to convert this DateTime: `2018-10-28 02:00:00` to a TimeStamp. Now the TimeStamp I am looking for is: `1540684800`, but with my code I get this TimeStamp: `1540688400`. I know it has something to do with my TimeZone, but I don't know how I can fix this.
I live in the Netherlands in Amsterdam.
Here is my code:

```
$LoopDateTime = "2018-10-28 02:00:00";
$search_key = (strtotime($LoopDateTime)*1000);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `1540688400` is correct for Amsterdam timezone. What timezone are you expecting?

Comment: I am sorry.... I want to get `1540684800`, but I get `1540688400`

Comment: Again, this is the correct timestamp for Amsterdam. Do you mean you want to get `1540688400`, but getting `1540684800` instead?

Comment: Yeah, I am so sorry!!!! Thats what I meant

Comment: I've deleted my answer since it's not relevant. try `strtotime('2018-10-28 02:00:00 CEST');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time zone identifier for Amsterdam is `Europe/Amsterdam` and `1540688400` *is* the correct timestamp. There's surely an online tool to check but you can also verify it from PHP itself:

```
$date = new DateTime("@1540688400");
$date->setDateTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
echo $date->format('r'); // Sun, 28 Oct 2018 02:00:00 +0100
```

However your code is not robust because depends on the configured timezone. You can just set it explicitly in a number of ways, e.g.:

```
$LoopDateTime = "2018-10-28 02:00:00";
$search_key = strtotime($LoopDateTime . ' Europe/Amsterdam') * 1000;
var_dump($search_key); // int(1540688400000)
```

Or:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$LoopDateTime = "2018-10-28 02:00:00";
$search_key = strtotime($LoopDateTime) * 1000;
var_dump($search_key); // int(1540688400000)
```

P.S. If I'm not wrong *Sunday 28 Oct 2018 02:00:00 +0100* is the exact moment when most Europe has just switched from *CEST (+0200)* to *CET (+0100)*.